# Linear program in three variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, linear-programming

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & 2x - 3y - z\\ \text{subject to} & x + y + z = 1\\ & x,y,z \geq 0\end{array}$$

One possible idea that comes into mind is the Lagrange multiplier approach where we could let $f(x,y,z) = 2x-3y-z, \quad $  $g(x,y,z) = x+y+z=1$ and $h(x,y,z) = x,y,z$; so that we could use
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \lambda\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} + \mu\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}, \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \lambda\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} + \mu\frac{\partial h}{\partial y} \text{ and } \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \lambda\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} + \mu\frac{\partial h}{\partial z}$$

But after second thought, I realized that $h(x,y,z)$  may not be a function which makes it difficult to use the Lagrange multiplier formula. I know there are multiplies way of solving such minimization problem (including graphical method in 3D - which is not readily available online, most online calculators are 2D) but I really don't know which one is the most convenient for this problem. Would appreciate any explicit solution to the problem.

Comment: Can you find the value of $x$ first?

Answer (score 2):

The linear programming dual problem is to maximize $\lambda$ subject to:
\begin{align}
\lambda &\le 2\\
\lambda &\le -3\\
\lambda &\le -1
\end{align}
Obviously, $\lambda = -3$ is optimal.  Complementary slackness then implies that $x=0$ and $z=0$, so the primal equality constraint implies that $y=1$.

Answer (score 0):

The much easier one is to solve for $z = 1-x-y$ and minimize $$2x-3y-(1-x-y) = 3x-2y-1$$ over $(x,y) \in [0,1]^2$.

---

**UPDATE**

Since you are minimizing linear function over $[0,1]$, best $x$ is at $1$ and $y = 0$ (since coefficient of $x$ is positive and coefficient of $y$ is negative). Hence, $x=1,y=0$ and this implies $z=0$ and you are done.

---

**UPDATE 2**

You are originally optimizing with constraints $x,y,z \ge 0$ and $x+y+z = 1$. The first constraint implies $x,y \ge 0$, and the second implies $x,y \le 1$, so you must have $0 \le x,y \le 1 \iff (x,y) \in [0,1]^2$.

As for producing minimum value, you are minimizing $F(x,y)=3x-2y-1$, and since $x$ has a positive coefficient, you have to pick the smallest possible value for $x$. Since $y$ has a negative coefficient in $F$, you want to pick the largest possible value for $y$, so the minimum occurs at $x=0,y=1$ with $F(0,1) = -3$.

If you were maximizing, the logic would flip and you would get $x=1,y=0$ with $F(1,0) = 2$.

Comment: If $f(x,y) = 3x-2y-1$, we have that $f_x = 3$ and $f_y = -2$. What do we do next?

Comment: @holala please see update

Comment: I have two unclear issues: (1) could you throw more light on the origin of the closed interval $(x,y) \in [0,1]^2$? and why not any other interval? (2) I am assuming without admitting that I am clear with the closed interval $(x,y) \in [0,1]^2$, using this interval resulted in two points producing the same minimum value, i.e., for $(x = 0, y=1) \implies f(x,y) = -3$ and for $(x = 1, y=0) \implies f(x,y) = -3$. So the best points are $(0,1)$ and/or $(1,0)$ where in each case $z=0.$ What do have to say?

Comment: @holala please see the second update

Comment: The second update is just the icing on the cake.

Answer (score 0):

This is a linear programming problem with compact feasible space, hence the optimal solution exists.

An optimal solution exists at the corner.

We want $y$ to be as large as possible. The optimal solution is $(0,1,0)$.

---

If you want to do it by Lagrangian approach. You can consider $h_1(x,y,z) =x$, $h_2(x,y,z) =y$, $h_3(x,y,z)=z$ and assign Lagrange multiplier $\mu_i, i = 1,2,3$.

Edit: Your $\mu$ is not correct.

We have $$2-\lambda - \mu_1 = 0$$
$$-3-\lambda-\mu_2 = 0$$
$$-1-\lambda - \mu_3$$

where $\mu_i \ge 0$.

Hence, $$\mu_1 = 2-\lambda \ge 0$$
$$\mu_2 = -3-\lambda \ge 0$$
$$\mu_3 = -1 -\lambda \ge 0$$

Hence $-3 \ge \lambda$, and hence $\mu_1 > 0$ and $\mu_3 > 0$. Hence by complementary slackness condition, $x=z=0$ and we conclude that $y=1$.

---

Remark: This question has a physical meaning, you have a choice of distributing resources into $x, y, z$ where $y$ gives you the most benefit. The optimal strangety is to invest everything to $y$.

Comment: using Langragian, $\mu_1 = 2$, $\mu_2 = -3$, $\mu_3 = -1$, and $g(x,y,z) = 1$ so how (if you could show me) can I obtain the optimal solution $(0,1,0).$

Comment: $g(x,y,z) = x+y+z=1$

Comment: I think you computation of $\mu$ is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

the solution is simple : it is $x=0,y=1,z=0$, it is not difficult to see why, try to get why intuitively and then find a formal elementary method to prove it.

Method :

Say $2x-3y-z = f$.

Now, choose a $x = \epsilon>0$ but then $f = 2\epsilon-3y-z > -3y-z \quad\forall y,z \geq 0$. So you have to choose $x=0$.

Now you know that $z=1-y$ so $f =-2y-1$. So $\min(f) = -3$ when $y=1$ and $z=0$.

Comment: Would appreciate if you suggest any elementary method for me.

Comment: @holala tell me what you think now , I updated :) ,

Comment: If $x=0$, wouldn't $-3y-2z=-3y-2z$  $\forall y, z \geq 0$ ? Also, how did $z=1-y$ came about?

Comment: If $x=0$ then the condition $x+y+z=1$ becomes $y+z =1$, for the first question I don't quite understand your question

Comment: ok if $x=0$ we should have that $ f= -3y-z = -3y-(1-y) = -2y-1$ not $-y-2$ right? Then, could you tell me why the restriction of $y=1$? If $y=0$ we could have much lower value for min$(f) = -1$ or using your function $f=-y-2$, min$(f) = -2$

Comment: Yes, there was a mistake in the $f$ , I re updated ! :D . But the minimum remains $-3 $ because when $ y = 0$ the $f$ is greater than when $y = 1$

Comment: Absolutely $-3<-1$ and you are right.